# Why is there no `elsunless` statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, language-design, conditional-statements

Ruby provides `unless` and `elsif` statements. It seems natural to assume that there would be a similar `elsunless` statement, but there is not. Is there a specific reason for this?

To illustrate, this statement would allow for code like this.

```
unless broken
  # do something
elsunless done
  # do something else
end
```

I'm aware that this code can be rewritten to use `if` and `elsif`, but in some cases using `unless` is clearer.

Comment: There is no `elseunless` because its meaning is not intuitive.

Comment: Actually, I would add the keyword `otherwise` and `otherwisif`. It rings so much better than `else`. Think of it: `if true puts "hi" otherwise puts "low" end`

Comment: In my opinion, `unless..else` is difficult to get your head around, particularly for people who aren't familiar with the code. I've never come across a case where it isn't improved by rewriting it using `if..else`. Adding another option would complicate the situation even further.

Comment: Here's a comment by Matz about it, unfortunately it's in Japanese. http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-list/16431

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic behind `if` / `else` statements usually is:

**Having one exception:**

```
if exception_a
  # do exception stuff
else
  # do standard stuff
end

unless exception_a
  # do standard stuff
else
  # do exception stuff
end
```

Adding `unless` in this case can be very useful, as you can switch around your code. What I also love about `unless` is that you can solely do your standard stuff while checking for an exception. (the `else` block can be left out)

**Having multiple exceptions:**

Here comes the tricky part:

```
if exception_a
  # do exception stuff a
elsif exception_b
  # do exception stuff b
else
  # do standard stuff
end

unless exception_a
  # do standard stuff
elsunless exception_b
  # do ???
else
  # do exception stuff
end
```

Besides being totally unreadable, I couldn't find a logical meaning to the `elsunless` block: What code would you put in there? I still have no idea if that would be some exception stuff or standard code.

Maybe you can explain further what code you would use in such a block.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby already provides `if`, `else`, `elsif`, and `unless`, so is there really a need to for `elsunless`? It looks like a hulking mammoth in a code. I think *Matz* doesn't see a reason to add the statement into a the ruby syntax.
Additionally, some of ruby coders investigate a ruby coding standard that excludes `unless` statement usage, which was inherited from *Perl*.

As for me, I would completely remove the `unless` keyword from the language.

Have a look at the [styling guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

Comment: Although I agree that `elsunless` would be a pain in the ass, I wouldn't go so far to remove `unless` from the language. When you get the hang of it, it becomes very useful.

Comment: `if !` is much shorter, and of course we can always use the DeMorgan's rule. =)

Comment: `if not` is even much shorter, and isn't a symbol.  Symbols are easy to skip past in reading code, and though we should pay attention, we also want to make it clear.  Semantically, ! means excitement, not 'not'.  It is valuable in expression not equal though.  Just my opinion.